# Android Studio Image Asset studio icons not centered

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to import a svg into an App icon with the built-in Android Asset Studio. But I'm facing an issue with the placement of the image. It's not centered. I've used it in the past without any issue.

Any idea why this is happening?

[image: Asset Studio]

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution yet?